# Cross Browsing peer to peer connection in webrtc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket, webrtc

I am new in webrtc and I want to make connection between my local peer to cross browser remote peer (assuming remote peer is located in other country or places). I have searched here and there but i cant understand how can I implement it in javascript. Instead i don't want to use any library. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean between different browser types or just different peers? Actual distance in miles will matter a bit with delay and such but using a good enough ICE server that both can access, it is very possible and not to complex.

Comment: but how can i implement it?
Do you have any tutorial link

Comment: [Peerconnection tutorial](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/WebRTC-PeerConnection.html) and [getting started tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/)